# Can I make Puppet's module-to-file mapping to start searching at the top of the modules tree?

Tags: puppet

Consider these two Puppet module files:

```
# File modules/a/manifests/b/c.pp
class a::b::c {
    include b::c
}

# File modules/b/manifests/c.pp
class b::c {
    notify { "In b::c": }
}
```

It seems that when Puppet hits the `include b::c` directive in class `a::b::c`, it searches for the corresponding *.pp file by looking backwards from the current class and decides that it find the correct file located at `../../b/c.pp`.  In other words, it resolves `b::c` to the same *.pp file that the `include b::c` statement appears in: `modules/a/manifests/b/c.pp`

I expected it (and would like it) to instead find and load the file `modules/b/manifests/c.pp`.  Is there a way to make Puppet do this?  If not, it seems to me that module names may not contain any other module names anywhere within them, which is a pretty surprising restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to force it to top use 'include ::b::c'